# same name function in different controller in symfony2 is not work in different path

Tags: php, symfony, controller

this is UserController file

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * @Route("/users", name="indexAction")
    */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $users = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Users')->findAll();
        return $this->render('admin/users.htmls.twig', array('users'=>$users));
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/users/add", name="addAction")
    */
    public function addAction()
    {
        return $this->render('admin/addusers.html.twig');
    }
}
```

and this is CmsController file:

```
class CmsController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * @Route("/cms", name="cmsAction")
    */
    public function cmsAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $cms= $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Cms')->findAll();
        return $this->render('admin/mcs.htmls.twig', array('cms'=>$cms));
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/cms/add", name="addAction")
    */
    public function addAction()
    {
        return $this->render('admin/addcms.html.twig');
    }
}
```

see the difference if i set addAction function not work but i set different name is work properly plz help how to call same name

Comment: please post the code and not pictures of it

Comment: is not possible bcos this code with / and star it sound like comment its not set in stackover flow

Comment: @ Altoyr plz give me solution

Comment: I have no idea, i am not a php-programmer.

Comment: its ok bro bt help to share my question if possible

Comment: the route name must be unique

Answer (score 2):

The internal route names need to be unique, please see [symfony: routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html):

> The [annotation name] is the internal name of the route, which doesn't have any meaning yet and just needs to be unique. Later, you'll use it to generate URLs.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mainly caused due to the same routs. As we can see your routes are fine please check you have enabled the mod_rewrite module on. If that does not solve your problem you can generate an issue on there official issue tracker on GitHub on the provided link
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/